# Creating date ranges from time stamp

Tags: sql-server

The query below grabs the max date from column `Time_Stamp` as StartDate from `Survey`. Adding 90 days to it for EndDate. Then creating 2 more ranges with 90 day intervals by just adding more to the original EndDate.

I'm trying to have the StartDate fall within 4 buckets of either Jan1st, April1st, July1st, or Oct1. If the Max Time_Stamp is before 1 of these dates then that will be the first StartDate of my ranges...So for my example below, the max Time_Stamp is June4th so the StartDate needs to be July 1st. Is this doable within sql server?

Time_Stamp for Hospital1

```
Time_Stamp
-----------
2014-06-04 16:01:14.000
2014-06-04 15:55:33.000
2014-06-04 15:45:05.000
2014-06-04 15:36:15.000
2014-06-04 15:00:34.000
2014-06-04 14:35:24.000
2014-06-04 14:04:50.000
2014-06-04 13:46:55.000
2014-06-04 13:23:57.000
2014-06-04 11:27:51.000
```

Current output:

```
StartDate   EndDate
----------- -----------
Jun  4 2014 Sep  2 2014
Sep  3 2014 Dec  2 2014
Dec  3 2014 Mar  3 2015
```

query

```
WITH Start AS
(
    SELECT 
           MAX(Time_Stamp) as StartDate, 
           DATEADD(day, 90, MAX(Time_Stamp)) as EndDate
    FROM Survey
    WHERE MainHospital = 'Hospital1'

),
Results AS
(
   SELECT StartDate, EndDate from Start
   UNION
   SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, EndDate), DATEADD(day, 91, EndDate) FROM Start
   UNION
   SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 92, EndDate), DATEADD(day, 182, EndDate) FROM Start
)
SELECT LEFT(StartDate,11) AS StartDate, LEFT(EndDate,11) AS EndDate FROM Results
```

Just an update, this gives me what I need for the 1st StartDate...

```
    --Return first day of next quarter
SELECT DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, MAX(Time_Stamp)) + 1, 0)
FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = 'Hospital1'
```

Comment: Possibly including something like this `DATENAME(Quarter, CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), Time_Stamp) AS DATETIME))`

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Year DATE = '2013-01-01'
DECLARE @Quarter INT = 1;

SELECT  DATEADD(QUARTER, @Quarter - 1, @Year) ,
        DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(QUARTER,  @Quarter, @Year))
```

You can use DATEPART(QUARTER, @Date) to figure out which quarter the record being selected and then you can use this query to find the begin/end dates of that quarter.

Use it like this:

```
SELECT  DATEADD(QUARTER, DATEPART(QUARTER, Time_Stamp) - 2, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, Time_Stamp), 0)) AS StartDate,
        DATEADD(SECOND, -1, DATEADD(QUARTER,  DATEPART(QUARTER, Time_Stamp) - 1, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, Time_Stamp), 0))) AS EndDate
FROM Hospital1
```

Comment: That looks useful but no idea how to incorporate into my query and my column Time_Stamp

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are just trying to calculate the quarter of your date, Am i correct?

If so, you can just use:

```
SELECT DATENAME(Quarter, CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE()) AS DATETIME)) as Quarter
```

Comment: yep! just found that, not sure how to include it in my query since I'm doing creating the 90 day intervals.

Comment: so are you also looking for the start and end date of that quarter?

Comment: Yes, select the TOP 1 MAX of the Time_Stamp, determine which quarter is NEXT from that date(not the current), and have that as the 1st StartDate in my query where I add days to get the intervals.

Answer (score 0):

to calculate a quarters date ranges:

```
select DATEADD(qq, datediff(qq, 0, getdate()),0) as first

select dateadd(dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, datediff(qq, 0, getdate()) +1, 0)) as last
```